Find the number of zeros of $f(z) = 6z+z^3+e^{z-2}$ in the annulus $1 <|z|<2$
I was looking at this post for advice on how to use Rouche's theorem to find the number of zeros a function has in a given annulus. An old qualifying exam problem says

Find the number of zeros of $f(z) = 6z+z^3+e^{z-2}$ in the annulus $1 <|z|<2$

On $|z|=1$, choosing $h(z)=z^3$ gives $|f-g| <|f|$; hence, $f$ has $3$ zeros in $|z|<1$. On $|z|=2$, choosing $h(z) = z^3+6z$ gives
$$|f(z)-h(z)| = |e^{z-2}|  \leq e^{|z|-2} = e^0=1 <12+8+1 \leq |f(z)| $$
Now, $h(z)=z^3+6z=z(z+\sqrt{6}i)(z-\sqrt{6}i)$ has only one zero in $|z|<2$ since $|\pm \sqrt{6}i| > 2$. So $f$ has $3-1=2$ zeros in the annulus.
The part that I'm having doubts about is the part where I said $12+8+1 \leq |f(z)|$ because truthfully, the inequality is actually flipped because
$$|z^3+6z+e^{z-2}| \leq 2^3+6 \cdot 2 + e^{2-2} = 12+18 +1$$
But $e^{z-2}$ acts weird and it's easier to bound it above than to bound it below. How can I justify my choice of $h(z)$ better?

@MartinR No, you're correct; I agree it doesn't make sense now that I think about it. My argument is likely flawed in particular because of the error I made that I pointed out above.  Fortunately, Jose's answer corrects this mishap.

Of course that the inequality $12+8+1\leqslant|f(z)|$ doesn't make sense. But note that, if $|z|=2$, we have $|e^{z-2}|\leqslant1$ and\begin{align}\left|z^3+6z\right|&=\left|z^3-(-6z)\right|\\&\geqslant\left|\left|z^3\right|-|-6z|\right|\\&=\left||z|^3-6|z|\right|\\&=4\text{ (since $|z|^3=8$ and $6|z|=12$)}\\&>1\\&\geqslant\left|e^{z-2}\right|.\end{align}And now you can apply Rouché's theorem.

Notice that, if $|z|=1$, we have $$|-e^{z-2}|=e^{Re(z-2)}\leq e^{-1}< 5=|6z|-|z|^3\leq |6z+z^3|$$
and if $|z|=2$ we similarly get $$|-e^{z-2}|=e^{Re(z-2)}\leq 1< 4=|6z|-|z|^3\leq |6z+z^3|$$
Consequently, we can apply Rouche's Theorem and say that $f(z)=z^3+6z+e^{z-2}$ has the same number of zeroes as $6z+z^3$ in both $|z|<1$ and $|z|<2$, and so in the annulus $1<|z|<2$ too.
Given that $6z+z^3$ has no roots in that annulus, $f$ has no roots in the annulus either.

Rouché's theorem is not needed, only the lower triangle inequality.
For $1 \le |z| \le 2$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(z)| &\ge 6|z| - |z|^3 - |e^{z-2}| \\
&= |z| (\underbrace{6 - |z|^2}_{\ge 2}) - \underbrace{|e^{z-2}|}_{\le 1} \\
&\ge 2 |z| - 1 \\ &\ge 1
\end{align}
$$
which proves that $f(z) \ne 0$ in the annulus.

Actually this shows that $f$ has no zeros for $1/2 < |z| \le 2$. One can now iterate this process to get larger domains in which $f$ has no zeros.
By considering an annulus $ r < |z| \le 1/2$ the above estimate gives
$$
 |f(z)| \ge r (6-\frac 14) - e^{-3/2}
$$
from which follows that $f$ has no zeros for $0.04 \le  |z| \le 2$. Similar one can consider an annulus $2 \le z \le R < \sqrt 6$, and it is not difficult to show that $f$ has no zeros in
$$
 0.04 \le |z| \le 2.2 \, .
$$
That is a pretty good estimate, numerical calculations show that the roots of $f$ with smallest modulus are approximately
$$
 -0.022062 \text{ and } {-0.008585 \pm 2.456579 i} \, .
$$
